# dropzone.js doesn´t show the layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

I´m trying `dropzone.js` and want the layout like on this page [dropzonejs.com](http://dropzonejs.com) or this [Work with DropzoneJS](http://startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php#sec2)

I download the files here

> github.com/enyo/dropzone/releases/tag/v4.3.0

Include into my html code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Titel der Webseite</title>

 <script src="dropzone-4.3.0/dist/dropzone.js"></script> 
 <link href="dropzone-4.3.0/dist/basic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="dropzone-4.3.0/dist/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>
  <body>
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>

  </body>
</html>
```

But the layout looks like this [dropzonejs.com/examples/simple.html](http://dropzonejs.com/examples/simple.html).
Only if I add this css to my code

```
dropzonejs.com/css/style.css?v=1469536445
```

it looks like on [dropzonejs.com](http://dropzonejs.com).

But I can't find this css in the download files. And here [Work with DropzoneJS](http://startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php#sec2) they don´t use this css.

What´s wrong?

regards,
ebody

Comment: If you want to use there CSS then copy it from there website and paste it into a new css file. then link to it, where ever you want it

Comment: Yes, but i dont´t understand, why it is not in the download files and the documentation. Here it works without this css https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php#sec2

Comment: Its an uploading tool. You need to tell it where you want the upload to go.

Comment: I meant why it is not in the download files here https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/releases/tag/v4.3.0